# How to Connect to CRM Dynamics Online Odata endpoint LinqPad?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata, linqpad

I'm able to connect to self-hosted CRM sites just fine with the default Odata driver within LinqPad.  The URI I use in the "WCF Data Services (OData) Connection" dialog for self-hosted is in the format http://MyServer.com/MyOrgName/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc. The user name is in the format "domain\username".

When I attempt to follow the same format for an CRM Online instance, it doesn't work.
[image: CRM Online Connection]

I'm guessing it's either because of the https, or the windows live credentials, but don't know what steps to take to fix the problem...

Please note, I want to use the odata provider, not the CRM 2011 provider.  The odata provider gives me the URL to retrieve the data which is extremely helpful for javascript.  The CRM 2011 provider gives the fetch XML, which isn't what I want to use in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted LinqPad and they said they don't currently support Windows Live Authentication.  I'm guessing that one would have to write a plugin and use the logic from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/02/04/connecting-to-crm-online-2011-web-services-using-soap-requests-only.aspx) page to handle the authentication issues.