# CRM 2011 JavaScript How to access data stored in an entity passed from a lookup control?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, lookup, entities, dynamics-crm-online

As the question suggests, I need to find out how to access entity data that has been passed into a JavaScript function via a lookup.

JavaScript Code Follows:

```js
// function to generate the correct Weighting Value when these parameters change
function TypeAffectedOrRegionAffected_OnChanged(ExecutionContext, Type, Region, Weighting, Potential) {

var type = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Type).getValue();
var region = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Region).getValue();

// if we have values for both fields
if (type != null && region != null) {

    // create the weighting variable
    var weighting = type[0].name.substring(4) + "-" + region;

    // recreate the Weighting Value
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Weighting).setValue(weighting);
}
```

}

As you can see with the following line using the name operator I can access my Type entity's Type field.

```js
// create the weighting variable
var weighting = type[0].name.substring(4) + "-" + region;
```

I am looking for a way now to access the values stored inside my type object. It has the following fields `new_type`, `new_description`, `new_value` and `new_kind`.

I guess I'm looking for something like this:

```js
// use value of entity to assign to our form field
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(Potential).setValue(type[0].getAttribute("new_value"));
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Comic

Comment: a lookup contains only the `id`,`name` and `entityType` properties. In order to get other field values from the record is necessary to retrieve it using `REST` or `SOAP` endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST OData calls are definitely the way to go in this case.  You already have the id, and you just need to retrieve some additional values.  [Here is a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx) to get you started.  The hardest part with working with Odata IMHO is creating the Request Url's.  There are a couple tools, that you can find on codeplex, but my favorite, is actually to use LinqPad.  Just connect to your Org Odata URL, and it'll retrieve all of your entities and allow you to write a LINQ statement that will generate the URL for you, which you can test right in the browser.

For your instance, it'll look something like this (it is case sensitive, so double check that if it doesn't work):

```
"OdataRestURL/TypeSet(guid'" + type[0].Id.replace(/{/gi, "").replace(/}/gi, "") + "'select=new_type,new_description,new_value,new_kind"
```

Replace OdataRestURL with whatever your odata rest endpoint is, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thx for the help here. I looked at LINQpad but can't seem to connect it to my CRM. I get an error basically saying Check credentials and make sure windows identity foundation is installed. I'm sure the credentials are correct as I can login to plugin registration tool correctly with these details, and WIF is definitely installed. Any Ideas?

Comment: @ComicCoder Is it CRM online on local, or IFD?

Comment: Its CRM Online, Also I still can't actually get any data into my script it always errors.

Comment: LinqPad doesn't support the Windows Live http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276178.  The first step to debugging is just to past the URL as is into your browser.  If it returns the data you want, you know you have a problem with your script.  If it errors, than you know your URL is wrong ( Capitalization mismatch or just all around wrong)

Comment: Thanks for that I checked again by manually browsing for my OData endpoint and found that I was referencing my custom entity incorrectly (Capitalisation miss match)

Comment: It'll get you everytime, I swear.  Might want to look for an online compatible Odata builder helper.  If you have to work with FetchXml, I'd check this out (shameless self plug: http://www.dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2013/07/making-fetchxml-in-javascript-less.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes  Guido Preite is right. You need to retrieve the entity by the id which come form the lookup by Rest Sync or Async. And then get Json object. However for make the object light which is returned, you can mention which fields to be backed as part of the Json. Now you can access those fields which you want.