# How to Configure LINQPad to Connect to OData Endpoint for CRM IFD

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm-2013, linqpad

Previously I've used LinqPad "WCF Data Services 5.5 (OData 3) to connect to on premise installations of CRM without issue.  Now I'm attempting to connect to an IFD of CRM and it's not working.  I know LinqPad [won't work with Windows Live Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276178/how-to-connect-to-crm-dynamics-online-odata-endpoint-linqpad), but is there a way to get it to work with IFD?

Currently I get this error:

> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Any way to get it to connect to the OData Endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so as LinqPad [doesn't support claims based authentication](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/113/odata-service-and-oauth) and probably won't any time soon based on lack of demand, original posting date and the feature still not in there 12 months on from Joe's last posting.