# How to use LINQPad to find CRM schema metadata

Tags: dynamics-crm, linqpad

Does anyone know how to use LINQPad to find meta data, in particular list all many to many relationships, in CRM Dynamics?

Kind of like the equivalent to querying information_schema in SQL to get metadata about the database schema.

Comment: See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276178/how-to-connect-to-crm-dynamics-online-odata-endpoint-linqpad

Answer (score 0):

Related to Entity and attributes metadata you can use Entities

- EntityMapSet
- AttributeMapSet

Hope it helps