# How to connect to Dynamics CRM Online 2016 OData WebApi with LINQPad?

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm-online, linqpad, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

How to connect to Dynamics CRM Online 2016 OData WebApi with LINQPad?

I'm aware of the existing question ...

[How to Connect to CRM Dynamics Online Odata endpoint LinqPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276178/how-to-connect-to-crm-dynamics-online-odata-endpoint-linqpad)

... but this is related to the older SOAP end points

Comment: [LINQPad Driver for Dynamics CRM Web API](https://crmlinqpadwebapi.codeplex.com/) sounds like what you're looking for.